# Property 'spacing' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

can someone see what I am doing wrong?  I am getting an error property spacing does not exist on type defaulttheme.

there error is on this line... padding: theme.spacing(3),

I am using @mui/material@5.2.5
also using typescript

This is from following an example on netninja material tutorial.

below is my app.tsx

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme3 = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#fefefe",
    },
    // secondary: #dd63dd,
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "Rajdhani",
    // fontFamily: "Quicksand",
    fontWeightLight: 400,
    fontWeightRegular: 500,
    fontWeightMedium: 600,
    fontWeightBold: 700,
  },
});

const AskPage = React.lazy(() => import("./AskPage"));

const store = configureStore();
function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme3}>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Layout>
              <Routes>
                <Route path="" element={<Notes />} />
                <Route path="create" element={<Create />} />
              </Routes>
            </Layout>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

then on my layout.tsx file... this is how I am trying to use it.

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  return {
    page: {
      background: "#f1f1f1",
      width: "100%",
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    drawer: {
      width: drawerWidth,
    },
    drawerPaper: {
      width: drawerWidth,
    },
    root: {
      display: "flex",
    },
    active: {
      background: "#f4f4f4",
    },
    // appbar: {
    //   width: "calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)",
    // },
    // toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  };
});
```

Comment: what version of Material are you using? from your code it actually looks like you are using a mix of both 4 and 5

Comment: i just put it in my post... i think 4.12.3

Comment: should I be using a different version?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to app.tsx should do

```
declare module "@mui/private-theming" {
  interface DefaultTheme {
    spacing: (spacing: number) => string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have wrapped your whole app around `ThemeProvider` so all you just need to remove `const theme = createTheme();`

In your code above there is technically 2 variables with the same name. You are declaring one which you should remove, and then the other one is being declared within makeStyles.

As long as you have wrapped your app within `ThemeProvider` then you can just pull the theme out of makeStyles.

Comment: I removed it but still getting error.  I added my app.tsx.  does it have to do with the fact I am creating a theme there?